# Calculation of Lipschiz constant for Square Exponential kernel

Tags: gaussian-process, rbf-kernel

I am working with the Kernel function and want to calculate bounds using the concept of Lipschitz continuity. I do understand that the SE kernel is continuous, smooth, and differentiable. Is there any way to derive the Lipschitz constant **analytically** for the SE kernel or SE-ARD kernel?

$$k_{SE}(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{x}') =\sigma^2\exp\left(\frac{-(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}')^T(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}')}{2l^2}\right)$$

$\mathbf{x} \in \mathcal{X}$ and $\mathbf{x}$ is a $d$-dimension vector

Comment: You need to define a domain of definition first.Then you may take the supremum of the derivative over this domain.

Comment: @gg So if $\mathbf{x} \in \mathcal{X}$ and $\mathbf{x}$ is $d-$dimensional then I can take maximum of partial derivative vector of kernel. I think I will require to employ norm to make a maximum of the partial derivative of kernel single value. Can I use any norm in that case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Let $\phi(t) = \sigma^2 e^{-t^2/(2l^2)}$ and obtain its Lipschitz constant by computing its first derivative.
- Show that $h(x,x') = \|x-x'\|$ is Lipschitz and derive its Lipshitz constant.
- Write $k_{SE}(x,x') = \phi(h(x,x'))$.
- Show that the composition $f \circ g$ of two Lipschitz functions $f$ and $g$ is Lipschitz with constant no larger than the product the Lipschitz constants of $f$ and $g$.